# I Can't Respawn on a server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In one of my friend's servers in Minecraft I traveled to the End and could not get out of it as the portal was not working. I decided if I killed myself I should be able to spawn back in the normal world. But when I died I could not press the respawn or title screen button. I tried logging off and back on and it had no difference. I also can't type because chat will open and close in less then 0.0001 seconds. I can't disconnect or even reach the main menu as it does the same thing with chat. Someone please help and keep in mind I cannot type for them to respawn me or tp.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that a solution to a similar problem has been found on [this site](https://forums.atlauncher.com/thread-3948.html).

The solution presented on the site is:

1. Go to [this UUID resolver](http://mcuuid.net/) and search your username to find your UUID.
2. Download [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac).
3. Open the player's file, located at `/world/playerdata/[UUID].dat`, using NBTExplorer.
4. Edit the `DeathTime` parameter by double clicking it, and set it to `0`.
5. Save, and relaunch the server.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

For the people who are using hacks and tried to escape blocked portal by using blink and /kill and got stuck - just exit to the main menu and unmark 'blink' and 'noclip'.

Answer (score -4):

Option 1:Try to ask for OP. It might help!
Option 2:Ask for Creative mode!